# Halacha of cooking by non-religious Jews

Tags: kashrut-kosher

This question is hypothetical.

If there were a situation where a person lived with a family member (or family members, or a Jewish roommate, etc.) who does not believe in Judaism, but they typically cook for the family, they know and agree to respect all Kashrus laws, and you know that you can trust them, is this cooking acceptable?